# How can I identify these capacitor values?

Tags: capacitor, schematics, component-values

I’m trying to build the power supply from this schematic.
[image: schematic]
I’ve been purchasing the parts, but am confused about the capacitors I’ve labeled, especially became their numbers start with “R”. What are their values? What common sense can I use so I can continue to find this out myself?

Comment: Taking a wild guess:  I have seen a few cases where resistances were written a for example 1R1 to represent a 1.1 ohm resistor.  So, those might be 0.1 and 0.01 microfarad capacitors

Comment: I agree with ^^. Also look at the circuit, what is does and what would be appropriate: C4 0.01uF = 10 nF, C2, C5: 100 nF seem appropriate for supply decoupling around a 78L05 regulator. Then C10 is R1 so also 100nF, it's in parallel with a 220uF electrolytic so just providing some HF decoupling, 100 nF also seems appropriate.

Comment: How are you going to go about the diode D2, which is marked "*Hi-Fi special*" ?

Comment: Wow, those are some ancient transistors.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev I think that's literally a normal diode, and its purpose is just being explained on the schematic. When I look at the whole schematic, all diodes (that aren't zener or schottky) are marked that way.

Comment: The hi-fi special marking is a bit weird. Of all the components, a reverse protection diode is the last one I'd expect to be marked that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a couple of other commenters seem to think it reasonable, I'll go ahead and make an answer from my comment:

Taking a wild guess:

I have seen a few cases where resistances were written as for example 1R1 to represent a 1.1 ohm resistor.

So, those might be 0.1 and 0.01 microfarad capacitors.

Additionally, those values would make sense in the given positions for a 7805 linear voltage regulator.

Comment: This would be my interpretation as well. The use of R is usually exclusive to resistors, but this is the only reasonable interpretation of this numbering scheme. The 'base unit' for capacitors is either microfarad or picofarad, but since a 0.01 picofarad capacitor wouldn't make much sense, 0.01 μF is more likely.

Comment: I answered a question just like this a few months ago. Treat the 'R' as a decimal point. A real decimal point may not print good or large enough to see. More and more often I see nF being used instead of fractional uF values.

Comment: Another name for 'decimal point' is 'radix point'; you see that 'r' in places that have nothing to do with electronics.  (I use it when I'm writing fractional binary numbers, for instance: 1011r1001 gets less argument from the audience for some reason than 1011.1001).